# CSS responsive div, when height is set in pixels

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have a container div that it's height is set in pixels -- example: `height:500px`. Anything this div contains is responsive using `%` and keeping the aspect ratios perfectly. But of course when I resize the browser window making it smaller, the only div that stays with the same height is the container div. How could I make it responsive -- change the height of the container div when it has a given standard height in pixels to begin with ? Thanks very much in advance for any solution given.

I made a simple example here: http://jsfiddle.net/5j9jddbk/

Comment: You can remove the height, let height be set by inner elements. You can also set the height based on content width. Do you have maximum width of the parent element, the one that holds container?

Comment: @skobaljic Yes I know I can remove the height but I would like the user to have this choice. In the case that I am testing the parent element that holds the div is using the full browser width 100%.

Comment: Read about media queries, they allow you to apply CSS depending on device (and thus resolution of the screen).

Comment: Here's your answer - it's very special to me and is the basis of all of my responsive work: http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html

Comment: And how much space this div holds inside of 100% window width? Problem is: when this div begins to be smaller? It must be at some point.

Comment: @Paul I know how to change the div size using media queries. What I don't know is how to make the container div begin to resize with analogy to the given height. Example: `@media all and (max-width:1000px) { .container { ..start resizing.. } }`

Comment: @durduvakis Did you check the link I gave?  If that's sort of what you're looking for, I can write an answer including a media query for you

Comment: @ntgCleaner thanks, I am checking it right now

Comment: @skobaljic The parent element is 100% of the browser width and the `.container` is say `980px` width and is centered horizontally. It holds some content and background image. The user will choose a height for that `.container`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This link](http://mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html) describes it perfectly.

You need to find your aspect ratio of your desired element.  In your case it seems to be 640 by 200, which makes your aspect ratio have a percentage of 62.5%. (I only say this because the background image you're using is 640x200)

Using the code in the link provided, you just need to give your container a width, add a pseudo element of `:before` to it and give the `:before` a `padding-top` of `62.5%`.  Then you need to position your container absolutely inside of it.

So your container will need a few things on it.  First of all, use `box-sizing:border-box;` whenever you have padding or borders to deal with, then give it a position of `relative`

```
.container {
    width:100%;
    border:10px solid red;
    position:relative;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

After that, you need to add a `:before` pseudo element to it.  This will take the given width of it's container (which is 100%) and use the `padding-top` to make the height a ratio of the width:

```
.container:before {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    padding-top:62.5%;
}
```

After that, you just need to make sure your contents inside are positioned `absolute` and are 100% width and height.

```
.inner
{
    width:100%; height:100%;
    background:url('http://p1.pichost.me/640/1/1236135.jpg') no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size:100%;
       -moz-background-size:100%;
         -o-background-size:100%;
            background-size:100%;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:40px; color:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Here's the fiddle demonstration
http://jsfiddle.net/bcbvLLrc/

A suggestion I would make is to make another div just inside your container called `.content` then give these styles to content:

```
.content {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

This will make sure the content is the full size of your container, then you can style anything inside the content however you would like, for example, you can place extra columns or rows in your content without having to worry about anything overflowing anywhere.

Comment: wow this is intelligent, and how did you calculate the aspect ratio ? wow this was crazy !

Comment: Thank you!  All I did was find the width and the desired height.  In your case, the picture you were using was 640x400. Just divide 400 by 640.  400/640 = 0.625 multiply by 100 to go from a decimal to a percentage = 62.5%

Comment: I am amazed. This is genius stuff. I will make a php function to do this calculation and set the `.container:before{padding-top:###}` dynamically, once I want the user to choose the height of the container. I hope I will work ! otherwise I will have to find you and ask you again :-)

Comment: @durduvakis That's a great idea! I think you can make that work nicely. If you need me again, just come back here and leave a comment on my answer.

Comment: just came to tell you that it worked excellent :-) and all contents inside fit perfect without the extra `.content` div. Thanks again.

Comment: may I ask you a question though, how would you calculate the aspect ratio if the width is set to 100% ?

Comment: @durduvakis Of course! I am a designer by trade, so when I design in photoshop, I am able to see the width and height of my desired element.  If you're going off of something with 100%, then you might need to just play around with the padding-top to get it right.  If I were you, I would take a screenshot of the element in question, then find it's width, then you can put it in a photo editing program and work in a height there.

Comment: I've given the user a choice to set width/height. In the case of width they can choose full width 100%. So I could not think of how to calculate the aspect ratio (dynamically) this way, but I added an extra field for that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution where you set the height based on parent element's width:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="inner">resize me..
            <br>..make me smaller</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.container {
    padding-bottom:51%;
    position: relative;
    border:10px solid red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /* Because of border */
    background:url('http://p1.pichost.me/640/1/1236135.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size:100%;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:40px;
    color:#fff;
}
.inner {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5j9jddbk/6/) <---

Setting element's padding or margin using percent as a unit refers directly to parent element width. [Read more...](http://mattsnider.com/css-using-percent-for-margin-and-padding/)

Comment: this is an excellent solution. I will use this too. Can I vote for both answers ? :D